# Auto Scaling Without Load Balancer in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, autoscaling, gcp-load-balancer, google-cloud-compute-engine

Can someone help me with GCP autoscaling. I want to achive Auto Scaling Without using Load Balancer in GCP because the service which is running on the VM does not need any endpoint its more likely a kafka consumer where its only fetch the data from cluster and send it to DB so there is no load balancing.

so far i have successfully created instaces template and have define the minimum and maximum state there but thats only maintaining  the running state not perfroming autoscaling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [instance groups](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups) which is a collection of virtual machine (VM) instances that you can manage as a single entity.

[Autoscaling groups of instances](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/autoscaler) have managed instance groups which will autoscale as per requirement by using the following policies.

1. CPU Usage: The size of the group is controlled to keep the average processor load of the virtual machines in the group at the required level
2. HTTP Load Balancing Usage: The size of the group is controlled to keep the load of the HTTP traffic balancer at the required level
3. Stackdriver Monitoring Metric: The size of the group is controlled to keep the selected metric from the Stackdriver Monitoring instrument at the required level .
4. Multiple Metrics: The decision to change the size of the group is made on the basis of multiple metrics.

Select your required policy and create a managed group of instances which will autoscale your VM.Here in this document you can find the steps to create scaling based on [CPU usage](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/autoscaler/scaling-cpu), similarly you can create a required group.

For understanding attaching a [Blog](https://docs.wallarm.com/admin-en/installation-guides/google-cloud/creating-autoscaling-group/) refer to it for more information.